# Non IDR Picture NAL Units - 0x21 and 0x61 meaning

Tags: opencv, video-streaming, h.264

Does anyone know what does `0x21` and `0x61` means in h.264 encoded video stream?

I know that `0x01` means it's a `b-frame` and `0x41` means it's a `p-frame`. My encoded video gives me two `0x21` frame followed by one `b-frame`.

```
I 21 21 B 21 21 B......
```

What is this `0x21`?

Comment: Do your hex values indicate the first byte of the NALU?

Comment: @szatmary Please find the link below which contains the sequence of bytes.  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JcobN6NgK59nlyzcfY5FpnE6_ii7C6KvovXe1OBLmeE/pub 

This is the sequence of bytes i get. First one is SPS then PPS and then I frame , then I suppose P, P and  B... 
How do I differentiate between frames.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From H.264 spec:

> 7.3.1 NAL unit syntax
>
> - forbidden_zero_bit - 1 bit - shall be equal to 0.
> - `nal_ref_idc` - 2 bits - not equal to 0 specifies that the content of the NAL unit contains a sequence parameter set [...]
> - `nal_unit_type` - 5 bits - specifies the type of RBSP data structure contained in the NAL unit [...]

`0x21` and `0x61` make it NAL unit type 1 (Coded slice of a non-IDR picture) with different values for `nal_ref_idc`.

UPD. There is no one to one mapping of specific bit, esp. at fixed position from the beginning of the "frame" that says it's I/P/B frame. You will need to parse out the bitstream to read values per 7.4.3 Slice header semantics of H.264 spec (it is still doable in most cases since the value is real close to the beginning of the bitstream - check H.264 spec for details):

[image: <code>slice_type</code>]

Comment: So is this P frame or B frame?
nal_unit_type will return 01 for all 4 combination. ( 0x01, 0x21, 0x41, 0x61 )
So how do we know whether packet is B fame , P frame or I frame?

Comment: This answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 9):

First point, a NALu is not the same than as a frame. A frame can contain more that 1 NALu (but not less). A frame can also be made up of more than one slice type. A single frame can have I, B  and P slices. If it is an IDR frame, then EVERY slice of that frame must be IDR.

0x01 is NOT a B slice. it is a "Coded slice of a non-IDR picture". exactly like 0x21 and 0x61. It could be a I/B/P or p slice. you need to parse the slice_type to know more.

Comment: Can you give any example or reference to parse the NAL uni t and find slice_type (I/P/B)?

Comment: No I can not. The comment field will not allow me to type enough to answer. Please open another question.

Comment: @szatmary Access units Delimeter, when present, can be used to identify start and end of the frame. When AUD is not present, what is the correct way to parse the starting and ending of a frame? Could you kindly explain.

Comment: You must parse every nalu until every macro-block is accounted for.