# Understand NAL Unit of h.264 stream

Tags: parsing, h.264, encoder

NAL Units start code: 00 00 00 01 X Y

X = IDR Picture NAL Units (25, 45, 65)

X = Non IDR Picture NAL Units (01, 21, 41, 61) ; 01 = b-frames, 41 = p-frames

What does 61 mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non IDR Picture NAL Units - 0x21 and 0x61 meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551325/non-idr-picture-nal-units-0x21-and-0x61-meaning)

Answer (score 1):

1. "01 = b-frames, 41 = p-frames" this is incorrect
2. Specification is available online for free: http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264
3. Similar question was here just a few days ago: [Non IDR Picture NAL Units - 0x21 and 0x61 meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551325/non-idr-picture-nal-units-0x21-and-0x61-meaning)